# Unable to get property 'get_contentArea' of undefined or null reference

Tags: telerik, radeditor

Here am using Dynamic Rad Editor

```
 oEditor.OnClientLoad = "OnClientLoad()"
```

on calling this method my Rad Editor is not working it is disable,tools and Content area also disabled.

here is my javascript function

```
 function OnClientLoad(editor) {  
    editor.get_contentArea().style.height = "417px";     
   // editor.getContentAreaElement().style.height = (417) + "px";
```

}

Am getting this error 
Unable to get property 'get_contentArea' of undefined or null reference

```
   Dim oEditor As New Telerik.Web.UI.RadEditor()
    oEditor.ID = sField
    If bUnique = False Then oEditor.ID = sField & "[" & GetNextSeqNo.ToString & "]"
    oEditor.Height = iHeight * 20
    oEditor.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Pixel(iUltimateWidth)

    SetEditorProperties(oEditor)

 Private Sub SetEditorProperties(ByVal oEditor As Telerik.Web.UI.RadEditor)

    oEditor.OnClientLoad = "OnClientLoad"
    'oEditor.ContentAreaMode = EditorContentAreaMode.Iframe
    'oEditor.ContentAreaCssFile = "~/Scripts/thumb-scroller.css"

    oEditor.ToolbarMode = EditorToolbarMode.Default
    oEditor.EditModes = EditModes.Design
    oEditor.NewLineMode = EditorNewLineModes.Br

    Dim uploadImages As String() = New String() {"~/Temp/MMRImages"}

    oEditor.ImageManager.ViewPaths = uploadImages
    oEditor.ImageManager.UploadPaths = uploadImages
    oEditor.ImageManager.MaxUploadFileSize = 2000000
    oEditor.ImageManager.AllowMultipleSelection = False
    oEditor.ImageManager.EnableAsyncUpload = True
    oEditor.ImageManager.EnableImageEditor = False

    oEditor.EnsureToolsFileLoaded()
```

how to add this reference
please help me

Answer (score 1):

oEditor.OnClientLoad = "OnClientLoad()" should be

```
oEditor.OnClientLoad = "OnClientLoad"
```

Note the removed () at the end of the function name.

Comment: Even thought same problem

Comment: any other javascript errors on the page? Is there a link we can see it?
What if you completely remove the OnClientLoad event handler?